# Evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{{n-1 \choose k-1}}{k}\right)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

> Evaluate :  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{{n-1 \choose k-1}}{k}\right)$

Alright so I'm completely stumped, I've never evaluated a summation of $\displaystyle{n \choose k}$.

My best guess is to use the binomial theorem, but I don't know how to change this into a form I could use the theorem on.

A little guidance please?

Comment: yes, sorry my formatting is off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use the recurrence relation
$$\binom nk=\frac nk\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
and remember that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk=\cdots$

Comment: Alright, so does it make sense if I multiplied $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{{n-1 \choose k-1}}{k}\right)$ by n, and then took that summation, and then divided by n at the end?

Comment: It would be perfect!

Comment: So dividing by n after taking the summation is correct? Or would I have to divide by the summation of n since I already took the summation of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{n{n-1 \choose k-1}}{k}\right)$

Comment: It's correct since multiplication (and division) is distributive w.r.t. addition.

Comment: Thank you that clears it up!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to somehow see the function $\frac{x^k}{k}$ in the series and use a bit of calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{x^k}{k}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{d}{dx} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{x^k}{k}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}x^{k-1}=(1+x)^{n-1}$$ by the Binomial Theorem, so $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{x^k}{k}=\int (1+x)^{n-1} dx=\frac{(1+x)^n}{n}+\mathcal{C}.$$ Plugging in $x=0$ tells us that $\mathcal{C}=-\frac{1}{n}$, so we have the more general result $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{x^k}{k}=\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{n}.$$ In particular, taking $x=1$ gives the desired result.

Comment: nice and clean approach

Answer (score 1):

The hint given is already good.
In alternative you can proceed as follows
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{1 \over k}\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)} \quad \left| {\;1 \le n} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {{1 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}}\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = {1 \over n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {{n \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}}\left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k + 1 \cr}  \right)}  = {1 \over n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = {1 \over n}\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  - 1} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over n}\left( {2^{\,n}  - 1} \right) \cr} 
$$

Comment: So you solution brings up a few question for me. Going off of the hint above, the way I solved it was multiplying the summation by n turning it into $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk$. I took that summation giving me $2^{n}$, and then divided by n to undo my previous multiplication giving me ${2^{n} \over n}$ which is different from you answer. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Edit - I see i took the summation at the wrong index

Comment: @Brownie: you did not take into proper consideration the summation bounds.